# write a compound array to h5 in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, hdf5

I need to write a struct array like following to h5? How to do this? Thanks a lot!

```
wdata.serial_no   = int32(5);
wdata.temperature = 6.0;
wdata.pressure    = 7.0;

wdata_array{1} = wdata;
wdata_array{2} = wdata;
```

My trial：

```
% construct the struct array
wdata.serial_no   = int32(5);
wdata.temperature = 6.0;
wdata.pressure    = 7.0;

wdata_array{1} = wdata;
wdata_array{2} = wdata; 

% open the file
file = H5F.create ('test.h5', 'H5F_ACC_TRUNC',...
    'H5P_DEFAULT', 'H5P_DEFAULT');

% build the compound memtype
intType   =H5T.copy('H5T_NATIVE_INT');
sz(1)     =H5T.get_size(intType);

doubleType=H5T.copy('H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE');
sz(2)     =H5T.get_size(doubleType);

sz(3)     =H5T.get_size(doubleType);

offset(1)=0;
offset(2:3)=cumsum(sz(1:2));

memtype = H5T.create ('H5T_COMPOUND', sum(sz));
H5T.insert (memtype,...
    'serial_no', offset(1), intType);
H5T.insert (memtype,...
    'temperature', offset(2), doubleType);
H5T.insert (memtype,...
    'pressure', offset(3), doubleType);

ts_memtype = H5T.array_create(memtype, 2);

space = H5S.create_simple (1, 1, []);

dset = H5D.create (file, 'DS1', ts_memtype, space, 'H5P_DEFAULT');
H5D.write (dset, ts_memtype, 'H5S_ALL', 'H5S_ALL', 'H5P_DEFAULT', wdata_array);

H5D.close (dset);
H5S.close (space);
H5F.close (file);
```

Error: 
The number of input structure fields (0) does not match the number of H5T_COMPOUND members defined in the
file (3).

Answer (score -1):

I have had better luck using the [higher level Matlab hdf5 commands](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/high-level-functions.html):

Example using a function to create the HDF5

```
function struct2HDF5(inStruct,hdf5Name)
sFields = fieldnames(inStruct);
for sf = sFields.'    
    h5create(hdf5Name,['/' char(sf)], size(inStruct),'Datatype',class(inStruct(1).(char(sf))))
    h5write(hdf5Name,['/' char(sf)],[inStruct.(char(sf))])
end

>> wdata.serial_no   = int32(5);
>> wdata.temperature = 6.0;
>> wdata.pressure    = 7.0;

>> wdata_array(1) = wdata;
>> wdata_array(2) = wdata;

>> struct2HDF5(wdata_array,'test3.h5')
>> h5disp('test3.h5')
HDF5 test3.h5 
Group '/' 
    Dataset 'pressure' 
        Size:  1x2
        MaxSize:  1x2
        Datatype:   H5T_IEEE_F64LE (double)
        ChunkSize:  []
        Filters:  none
        FillValue:  0.000000
    Dataset 'serial_no' 
        Size:  1x2
        MaxSize:  1x2
        Datatype:   H5T_STD_I32LE (int32)
        ChunkSize:  []
        Filters:  none
        FillValue:  0
    Dataset 'temperature' 
        Size:  1x2
        MaxSize:  1x2
        Datatype:   H5T_IEEE_F64LE (double)
        ChunkSize:  []
        Filters:  none
        FillValue:  0.000000
>> press = h5read('test3.h5','/pressure')    
press =    
     7     7
```

Note that when you get the data back out it will be in an array.  Also you might need to be careful about having something in the structure that is a type that is not supported by HDF5 like a cell or a char array.

EDIT:
Here is the reverse function to make an array of structures from an HDF5.  Note that there are some assumption like each field is the same dimension, etc.

```
function outStruct = HDF52struct(hdf5Name)
fInfo = h5info(hdf5Name);
sFields ={fInfo.Datasets.Name};
sSize   = max(fInfo.Datasets(1).Dataspace.Size);
outStruct(sSize).(sFields{1}) = []; %Create struct array with the right number of elements
for sf = sFields 
    tempData = num2cell(h5read(hdf5Name,['/' char(sf)]));
    [outStruct.(char(sf))] = deal(tempData{:});
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But what I want to do is to save an struct array (wdata_array) but not a single struct.

Comment: Oops I missed that part of the question ... must have read it to fast.

Comment: @LiBowen  See my edited answer for an array of structs.  Note in my example I am using an a structure array & not a cell array of structs.

Comment: Clever solution! But when I want to read the h5 file again, the structure will be lost. That means, with tmp = h5read('test3.h5', '/pressure') I only get an array of pressure but not the original struct array. Do you still have a solution with low-level HDF5 API?

Comment: There is not a native way to write and read structures to HDF5 like you want. However, you could make your own "read function" ... basically the reverse of my `struct2HDF5`.

Comment: ... well I take back there is "not a way"  ... it is apparently possible but difficult and probably not worth the effort.

Comment: See my edit for the reverse HDF52strcut still not a compound data type like your were after.  However, it is simpler in a way if some of the assumptions hold (1 element per field in a struct, all fields the same number of elements, etc.)

Comment: Maybe this would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55539831/write-matrix-data-to-each-member-of-datatype-in-hdf5-file-via-matlab