# Write Matrix Data to Each Member of Datatype in HDF5 file via MATLAB

Tags: matlab, dataset, hdf5

This is my first go at trying to create an HDF5 file from scratch using the [Low-Level commands](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/low-level-functions.html?searchHighlight=low%20level%20hdf5&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) via MATLAB.

My issue is that I am having a hard time trying to write data to each specific member in the datatype on my dataset.

First, I create a new HDF5 file, and set the right layer of groups:

```
new_h5 = H5F.create('new_hdf5_file.h5','H5F_ACC_TRUNC','H5P_DEFAULT','H5P_DEFAULT');
new_h5 = H5G.create(new_h5,'first','H5P_DEFAULT','H5P_DEFAULT','H5P_DEFAULT');
new_h5 = H5G.create(new_h5,'second','H5P_DEFAULT','H5P_DEFAULT','H5P_DEFAULT');
```

Then, I create my datatype:

```
datatype = H5T.create('H5T_compound',20);
H5T.insert(datatype,'first_element',0,'H5T_NATIVE_INT');
H5T.insert(datatype,'second_element',4,'H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE');
H5T.insert(datatype,'third_element',12,'H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE');
```

Then, I format that into my dataset:

```
new_h5 = H5D.create(new_h5,'location',datatype,H5S.create('H5S_SCALAR'),'H5P_DEFAULT');
subset = H5D.get_type(H5D.open(new_h5,'/first/second/location'));
mem_type = H5T.get_member_type(subset,0);
```

I receive an error with the following command:

```
H5D.write(mem_type,'H5ML_DEFAULT','H5S_ALL','H5S_ALL','H5P_DEFAULT',data);
```

> Error using hdf5lib2
>
> Unhandled HDF5 class (H5T_NO_CLASS) encountered. It is not possible to write to this attribute or dataset.

So, I try this method instead:

```
new_h5 = H5D.create(new_h5,'location',datatype,H5S.create_simple(2,dims,dims),'H5P_DEFAULT'); %where dims are the dimensions of all matrices of data structure
H5D.write(mem_type,'H5ML_DEFAULT','H5S_ALL','H5S_ALL','H5P_DEFAULT',data); %where data is a structure
```

I receive an error with this following command:

```
H5D.write(mem_type,'H5ML_DEFAULT','H5S_ALL','H5S_ALL','H5P_DEFAULT',data);
```

> Error using hdf5lib2
>
> Attempted to transfer too many values to or from the library buffer.

When looking [here](http://health.ahs.upei.ca/KubiosHRV/MCR/resources/MATLAB/en/imagesci/hdf5dataset.xml) for the XML tags for the error messages, it describes the above error as "illegalArrayAccess." Apparently, according to [this question](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/379825-attempted-to-transfer-too-many-values-to-or-from-the-library-buffer-when-using-hdf5-library), you can only write to 4 members without the buffer throwing an error?

Is this correct? How can I correctly write to each member. I am about to reach my mental limit trying to figure this one out.

***EDIT***:

References kept here for general information:

[HDF5 Compound Datatypes Example](https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/examples/misc-examples/h5_array_compound.c)

[HDF5 Compount Datatypes](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/wilkins.5/computing/HDF/hdf5tutorial/compound.html)

[H5D.write MATLAB Command](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/h5d.write.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out why I cannot write data. I have solved the problem. I had my dimensions set incorrectly (which is code I forgot to include originally). My apologies. I had my dimensions like this:

```
dims = fliplr(size(data_matrix));
```

Where dims was a 15x250 matrix. The error was in that the buffer was unable to write a 250x15 matrix for each member, because it only had data for a 250x1 for each member.

The following code will (generically) work for writing data to each member:

```
new_h5 = H5F.create('new_hdf5_file.h5','H5F_ACC_TRUNC','H5P_DEFAULT','H5P_DEFAULT');
new_h5 = H5G.create(new_h5,'first','H5P_DEFAULT','H5P_DEFAULT','H5P_DEFAULT');
new_h5 = H5G.create(new_h5,'second','H5P_DEFAULT','H5P_DEFAULT','H5P_DEFAULT');
datatype = H5T.create('H5T_compound',20);
H5T.insert(datatype,'first_element',0,'H5T_NATIVE_INT');
H5T.insert(datatype,'second_element',4,'H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE');
H5T.insert(datatype,'third_element',12,'H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE');
dims = fliplr(size(data_matrix)); dims = [1 dims(1,2)];
new_h5 = H5D.create(new_h5,'location',datatype,H5S.create_simple(2,dims,dims),'H5P_DEFAULT'); 
H5D.write(new_h5,'H5ML_DEFAULT','H5S_ALL','H5S_ALL','H5P_DEFAULT',data_structure);
```

where `data_matrix` is a 15x250 matrix containing all data, and where `data_structure` is a sctucture containing 15 fields, each 250x1 in size.